# Why is CloudFront working via one CNAME record but not another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

So assume company name is **widget**

I have elastic beanstalk instance at **widget.elasticbeanstalk.com**
I have a domain name **widget.com** under Route53 control
I have a CNAME record **direct.widget.com** pointing to **widget.elasticbeanstalk.com**
I have another  CNAME record **search.widget.com** also pointing to **widget.elasticbeanstalk.com**

This works fine I can access my eb instance via **search.widget.com** and **direct.widget.com**

I then setup Cloudfront to use origin **direct.widget.com** with alternate domain name of **cache.widget.com**, and I configure another CNAME on Route53 from **cache.widget.com** to my cloudfront instance (lets call this **drvevtora80lk.cloudfront.net**)

This also works fine I can access my Cloudfront instance via **cache.widget.com** and this will recognise already cached data and work or go to **direct.widget.com** as necessary.

But my users are using **search.widget.com** and I want them to now go via Cloudfront rather than directly to the server. So I now modify the **search.widget.com** CNAME to point to **drvevtora80lk.cloudfront.net** and wait a while for changes to propogate.

But now using **search.widget.com** gives me a Cloudfront error

The **cache.widget.com** and **direct.widget.com** continue to work fine, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that although I modified the search.widget.com CNAME to point to drvevtora80lk.cloudfront.net I forgot to add search.widget.com as an alternate name within my Cloudfront distribution, adding that and it now works.